# Convert php page to pdf on the fly

Tags: php, html, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

I want to convert page like this http://alexking.org/projects/html-resume-template/demo/resume.php to pdf on the fly by a link inside the page, I tried dompdf but failed to have the result.

Answer (score 3):

I has some success with [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default), give it a try.
Example:

```
$content = get_include_contents('/resume.php');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('example.pdf');
```

Comment: if resume.php page on my root, how I can use this to convert the the page resume.php from another php file?

Comment: See my edited answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Zend_PDF()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html), which provides all possibilities. If you need a bigger freedom and other formatting, I'd recommend to use latex and a `latex2pdf`-call, but this one might be a bit much for what you want to achieve.

Unfortunatly, I haven't seen a decent html2pdf-generator so far.

Comment: It's a PDF generator, it doesn't take HTML/CSS as input

Answer (score 0):

What about http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php ?

Comment: It's a PDF generator, it doesn't take HTML/CSS as input

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be very good http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/. It uses the webkit engine.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). It fully supports UTF-8 and you don't need any external libraries to use it.

Comment: It's a PDF generator, it doesn't take HTML/CSS as input

Comment: Call it as you want but it's able to solve the problem...

Comment: TCPDF is very good but it's writeHTML() functionality is limited.  It doesn't do a great job with tables for example and ignores CSS.  I found wkhtmltopdf and Snappy (https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) to be a lot better.